# How to resolve this error while installing devstack kilo on ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, openstack, devstack

This is what I did:

1) Cloned devstack kilo using the command:

git clone https://github.com/openstack-dev/devstack.git -b stable/kilo

2) cd devstack

3) ./stack.sh

**I get the following error while installing devstack kilo on ubuntu.**

```
You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 8.0.2 is available. You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
+ local 'test_req=testtools>=0.9.36,!=1.2.0,<2.0.0/test-requirements.txt'
+ [[ -e testtools>=0.9.36,!=1.2.0,<2.0.0/test-requirements.txt ]]
+ pip_install_gr os-testr
+ local name=os-testr
++ get_from_global_requirements os-testr
++ local package=os-testr
+++ grep -i -h '^os-testr' /opt/stack/requirements/global-requirements.txt
+++ cut -d# -f1 grep: /opt/stack/requirements/global-requirements.txt: No such file or directory
++ local required_pkg=
++ [[ '' == '' ]]
++ die 142 'Can'\''t find package os-testr in requirements'
++ local exitcode=0
++ set +o xtrace [ERROR] /home/nikhil/devstack/inc/python:142 Can't find package os-testr in requirements
+ local 'clean_name=[Call Trace] ./stack.sh:715:pip_install_gr /home/nikhil/devstack/inc/python:63:get_from_global_requirements /home/nikhil/devstack/inc/python:142:die'
+ pip_install '[Call' 'Trace]' ./stack.sh:715:pip_install_gr /home/nikhil/devstack/inc/python:63:get_from_global_requirements /home/nikhil/devstack/inc/python:142:die
++ set +o
++ grep xtrace
+ local 'xtrace=set -o xtrace'
+ set +o xtrace
+ sudo -H http_proxy= https_proxy= no_proxy= PIP_FIND_LINKS=file:///opt/stack/.wheelhouse /usr/local/bin/pip install '[Call' 'Trace]' ./stack.sh:715:pip_install_gr /home/nikhil/devstack/inc/python:63:get_from_global_requirements /home/nikhil/devstack/inc/python:142:die Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 211, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 282, in run
    wheel_cache   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 272, in populate_requirement_set
    wheel_cache=wheel_cache   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 213, in from_line
    wheel_cache=wheel_cache, constraint=constraint)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 67, in __init__
    req = pkg_resources.Requirement.parse(req)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2980, in parse
    reqs = list(parse_requirements(s))   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2911, in parse_requirements
    raise RequirementParseError("Missing distribution spec", line) RequirementParseError: Missing distribution spec [Call You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 8.0.2 is available. You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
+ exit_trap
+ local r=2
++ jobs -p
+ jobs=
+ [[ -n '' ]]
+ kill_spinner
+ '[' '!' -z '' ']'
+ [[ 2 -ne 0 ]]
+ echo 'Error on exit' Error on exit
+ generate-subunit 1455806136 50 fail ./stack.sh: line 463: generate-subunit: command not found
```

**Here is the screenshot:**

[image: devstack installation error]

I think that the error is caused by the python package. I updated python and tried again but no avail.

**What is the error and how can I solve it please?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip

sudo pip install --upgrade pip
```

Looks like I've installed and upgraded python.

I remember trying this before but it didn't work. I don't know why, but it worked now.

It would be helpful if anyone can state the reason behind the error and delineate the solution.

Answer (score 4):

In your command line:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
sudo pip install -U os-testr
```

This worked fine for me...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
sudo pip install -U os-testr
```

Source: https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/88189/open-stack-installation-i-got-an-error/?answer=88228#post-id-88228

Comment: No, I haven't tried that earlier. I ran that today, but it gave me an error. After I managed to install successfully (see my answer), your command ran well, but I stopped it in the middle since I've already achieved my purpose. Thanks for your contribution. :)